# Close firefox webpage and debug

Tags: c#

My following code has two problems.

1- It doesn't go to the next row in dataset (when I run it, it just run firefox for 2916 times). I change this it from

```
var test = url.Replace("<userid>", Convert.ToString(row[userID]));
```

to

```
var test = url.Replace("<userid>", Convert.ToString(row["userID"]));
```

but it shows an error (Column 'userid' does not belong to table).

2- I want to close the firefox webpage page at the end of each loop and for next loop it runs again(because of performance issue)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Net;

namespace test2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\hidden.accdb";
            conn.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = "Select * from hidden";
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            //To read data from dataset
            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
            //Store the userID
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            int userid=0,trackid=0;
            int counter=0;
            foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                string url = "http://abcd/<userid>?groups=<userid>";
                var test = url.Replace("<userid>", Convert.ToString(row[userid]));
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url);
                string client = (new WebClient()).DownloadString("http://abcd/userid?groups=userid");
                if (client.ToLower() == (Convert.ToString(trackid).ToLower()))
                {
                    counter++;
                }
                int ave = counter / 2916;
                MessageBox.Show("Average = " + counter);
            }
            conn.Close();
            }

}
}
```

Comment: This is a C# question. Please do not use the C tag.

Comment: By the way, you don't need to start every question with "I am a begginer programmer, my following code has problems" ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
string url = "http://abcd/<userid>?groups=<userid>";
var test = url.Replace("<userid>", Convert.ToString(row["userid"])); // You need ""
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(test); // You should use variable test, which contains your url with <userid> replaced.
```

Comment: If I understand it right, I must change it o the following codes:     
 string url = "http://abcd/<userid>?groups=<userid>";
                var test = url.Replace("<userid>", Convert.ToString(row["userid"]));
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(test);
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url);